# How to set the width of the label of a description to the width of a string of text in ConTeXt?

Tags: context, description, dimensions

I am using `\startdesc{}` to create a label and description environment, e.g.:

```
\startdesc{(label)}
    This is some text in a sentence.
\stopdesc

\startdesc{(another label)}
    This is some more text in another sentence.
\stopdesc
```

Unfortunately, this results in labels which are of different length and the sentences begin at a different starting distance relative to the left margin.

```
(label)  This is some text in
   a sentence.

(another label)  This is some
   more text in another sent-
   ence.
```

How can I set the width of all of the labels to a fixed width, to the width which would be appropriate for the string `WWWWWWWW`, which never actually appears in the document?

```
(WWWWWWWW)  This is some text
   in the first sentence.

(label)     This is some text
   in a sentence.

(another labTlis is some
   more text in another sent-
   ence.
```

Comment: You can set the width to a fixed value using `\definedescription[desc][width=3cm,…]`, this is however not related to the longest label.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\setwidthof` to find the width of a string:

```
\setwidthof A really really long long Long word \to \WIDTH
```

For descriptions you can use the `width` key to set the width of the labels:

```
\definedescription[desc][width=\WIDTH]
```

Comment: This command results in an error, "Undefined control sequence" with ConTeXt  ver: 2011.05.18.

Comment: @VIllage: If you are using ConTeXt MkIV, then you must update the context distribution. In the last one year, almost all of the internals of MkIV have been rewritten.