# What is the plain TeX equivalent of \settowidth?

Tags: tex-core, lengths, dimensions

The `\settowidth` command, which sets a width equal to the width of some text, is described at [Get width of a given text as length](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18576/get-width-of-a-given-text-as-length) and [How to set the width of the label of a description to the width of a string of text in ConTeXt?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51992/how-to-set-the-width-of-the-label-of-a-description-to-the-width-of-a-string-of-t). What is the plain TeX equivalent of this command?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is none other than doing the same thing by copying the LaTeX definition:

```
\catcode`@=11
\newbox\@tempboxa
\def\@settodim#1#2#3{\setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{{#3}}#2#1\@tempboxa
   \setbox\@tempboxa\box\voidb@x}
\def\settoheight{\@settodim\ht}
\def\settodepth {\@settodim\dp}
\def\settowidth {\@settodim\wd}
\catcode`@=12
```

Now `\settowidth\mylen{xyz}` would become

```
\@settodim\wd\mylen{xyz}
```

so transformed into

```
\setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{{xyz}}
\mylen\wd\@tempboxa
\setbox\@tempboxa\box\voidb@x
```

and the trick is done, assuming you already allocated

```
\newdimen\mylen
```

Comment: In the middle line of the three-line code snippet, should that be `\wd` rather than `\ht`? By the way, is `\@tempboxa` defined in Plain-TeX? (If not, one can just create a new "scratch" box with that name, right?) Separately, it may be useful to remind readers that they'll need to "wrap" these instructions in the usual `\catcode\`@=11` ... `\catcode\`@=12` pair.

Comment: You're right about `\ht` that should be `\wd`; the second part is just to show the working of the macros, not actual input.

Answer (score 14):

You can set your wanted content into a box with `\setbox`

```
\setbox0\hbox{some horizontal material}
```

where `0` is a “scratch” box register, or you can assign a new box register number with `\newbox`

```
\newbox\mybox
```

after which you can use that, as in

```
\setbox\mybox\vbox{some vertical material}
```

Now you can ask for its dimensions with

```
\the\ht\mybox for its height,
\the\wd\mybox for its width, and
\the\dp\mybox for its depth
```

(where the prefix `\the` typesets the quantity)

So to answer the question,

```
\newbox\mybox
\newdimen\mydim
\def\setMyDimToMyBoxWidth#1{%
  \setbox\mybox\hbox{#1}% 
  \global\mydim=\wd\mybox% global so the dim can be used outside
  \leavevmode% in case it's the first thing in a paragraph
  \box\mybox% typeset the contents of the box
}

Some text \setMyDimToMyBoxWidth{some horizontal material} more text
now, the width is \hbox to\mydim{\hfil\the\mydim}.
\bye
```