# ConTeXt: Macro to get character width

Tags: macros, context, characters, strings

## Background

Looking to adjust the location of the first letter in a word based on its width.

## Problem

The calculation resembles:

```
\define[1]\StyleChapterChar{%
  \cldcontext{string.sub("#1",1,1)}%
}

% Use a nested frame to keep the overlain large letter together with
% the chapter title.
\define[1]\StyleChapter{%
  \StyleChapterFramed{%
    \framed[align=right, frame=off]{%
      \startoverlay
        \color[blue]{%
          \StyleChapterChar{#1}%
        }
        \vskip-1.9em\hskip\dimexpr\averagecharwidth*33/10#1
      \stopoverlay
    }
  }
}
```

Here, `3.3 * \averagecharwidth` is used to offset the text. This causes the horizontal offset of the emphasized first character in the word to vary wildly between an `A` and an `I`. What I would like is to replace this calculation (`3.3 * \averagecharwidth`) with one that uses the character width (e.g., `3.3 * \charwidth{\StyleChapterChar}`)

## Question

How do you get the width of a single character, when you don't know what that character is?

## Ideas

I've tried a few things so far:

```
\define[1]\StyleChapterCharWidth{
  \dimexpr\fontcharwd\font`#1
}

\define[1]\StyleChapterCharWidth{
  \fontcharwd\font`#1
}
```

It seems like the back-tick (`) character indicates that the next character should be treated literally.

## Related

- https://gitorious.org/context/context/source/8e052e94b8b3ca08900ab4fe0a5bf110f6a52327:tex/context/base/lang-frq.mkii
- [Determine width of verbatim characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113648/determine-width-of-verbatim-characters)
- [How to set the width of the label of a description to the width of a string of text in ConTeXt?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51992/how-to-set-the-width-of-the-label-of-a-description-to-the-width-of-a-string-of-t)

Comment: Typeset the character in a box, and measure its width. `\setbox\scratchbox\hbox{C}\wd\scratchbox`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Aditya's clue:

```
\define[1]\StyleChapterChar{%
  \cldcontext{string.sub("#1",1,1)}%
}

\define[1]\StyleChapter{%
  \StyleChapterFramed{%
    \framed[align=right, frame=off]{%
      \startoverlay
        % Calculate the offset of the large letter based on the width of
        % the character. This allows the font to change without significantly
        % affecting the distance between the emphasized first character of the
        % chapter title and the complete chapter title.
        \setbox\scratchbox\hbox{%
          \StyleFontChapterCharacter\StyleChapterChar{#1}}%
        % Shift the first character back relative to the chapter title.
        \hskip-.55\wd\scratchbox%
        \color[blue]{%
          \StyleFontChapterCharacter%
          \StyleChapterChar{#1}%
        }
        \vskip-1.9em
        #1
      \stopoverlay
    }
  }
}
```